# iMessage App Does Not Appear in iPhone Simulator in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Context: I am developing an iMessage app and an iPhone app in Swift using Xcode. Both apps are designed to communicate with each other via a shared data container (group.BTSharedData). The data shared is simply the state of certain toggles in the iPhone app which is to be reflected in the iMessage app.

Problem: The main iPhone app builds and runs perfectly in the simulator. However, after restarting the simulator by erasing all content and settings, I can't get the iMessage app to even show up. This is despite the fact that it was building and running fine before. Additionally, print statements within the iMessage app don't appear to be executing.

Desired Behaviour: I expect the iMessage app to appear in the simulator and the print statements to execute, which would indicate that the communication between the two apps is successful.

To reproduce this problem, here's the simplified code and setup:

1. Set up two apps in the same project: an iMessage app and an iPhone app.
2. Set up a shared data container (App Groups) between the two apps with the name "group.BTSharedData".
3. In the iPhone app, use UserDefaults with suiteName "group.BTSharedData" to store and retrieve toggle states. Sample code for this:

```swift
class SettingsViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var boratToggle: Bool {
        didSet {
            saveToggleState(for: "Borat", state: boratToggle)
        }
    }

    private let userDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.BTSharedData")

    init() {
        let defaultValues = ["Borat": false]
        userDefaults?.register(defaults: defaultValues)
        boratToggle = userDefaults?.bool(forKey: "Borat") ?? true
    }

    private func saveToggleState(for key: String, state: Bool) {
        userDefaults?.set(state, forKey: key)
    }
}
```

4. In the iMessage app, try to fetch the state of the toggles from UserDefaults with suiteName "group.BTSharedData". Here's some sample code for this:

```swift
let userDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.BTSharedData")
print("Borat: \(userDefaults?.bool(forKey: "Borat"))")
```

5. Run the simulator. Observe if the print statement executes and if the iMessage app appears in the simulator.

I have already tried restarting and updating both Xcode and my Mac, cleaning the build folder, and testing the app on my iPhone. I'm unable to figure out why the iMessage app is not appearing and why the print statements are not executing.

Here is the link to the complete code in the GPT thread for your reference: https://chat.openai.com/share/4b5cf6d3-f4cc-4bfe-8a04-3495cee8d9d8